# I have a problem while fetching date in "class in C:\xampp\htdocs\ERP\std.php on line 4" from ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new in ajax. i have a problem. i'm selecting value from select tag and sending it into ajax code that give me record at realtime but it display nothing in next select tag. if i tried to open second php file. it diplay error like, "Notice: Undefined index: class in C:\xampp\htdocs\ERP\std.php on line 4". i don't know what to do. help me.
Here is my code of ajax

```
<script>
        function myfunction(datavalue) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'std.php',
                data: { class : datavalue},

                success: function(response){
                    $('#stdName').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

option from where i am getting value

```
 <select name="std-class" onchange="myfunction(this.value)" id="stdClass">
                                        <?php if(isset($_GET['fee_id'])){?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['std_class']; ?>"><?php echo $row['std_class'];?></option>
                                        <?php }else {?>
                                        <option>Select Class</option>
                                        <?php }
                                        $std=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT class_name FROM classes");
                                        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($std)){
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row1['class_name'];?>"><?php echo $row1['class_name'];?></option>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </select>
```

And this is the php file code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sms_db");

$class=$_POST['class'];
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE class='$class' ORDER BY id ASC");
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows['username'];?>"><?php echo ucwords($rows['name']);?></option>
<?php }
?>
```

I also tried this code but it also not working

```
<script>
        function myfun() {
            var select = document.getElementById('stdClass').value;
            console.log(select);
            $.post("std.php", {
                   class: select
                   },
                   function(response) {
                    $('#stdName').html(response);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: There should not be any problem. I would change the POST parameter name from class to class_name or smth just to be sure this is not causing any error. Open up inspector tools (F12 in chrome)  check your network and look at XHR responses, see if anything is being returned.

Comment: it show 2 error 1) contentDocumentStart.js (status) failed 2) contentDocumentStart.js (status) 403. When i select value from select it show std (status) 200

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: There is url routing problem in my code that's why i am getting problem. But thanks to all of you for sharing your reviews and help

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
    function myfunction(datavalue) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'std.php',
            data: { "class" : datavalue},
            success: function(response){
                $('#stdName').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is good form to add an explanation of what the code is doing, to explain why your solution answers the question - particularly useful for novices looking to learn from examples